# Xamarin Mobile App cannot connect to on-premises Web API via IIS

Tags: xamarin, iis, webapi

We have a Xamarin Mobile App that connects to a Web API. The WEB API is hosted on prem using IIS.

We can use Postman to obtain a Token and then call one of the Endpoints i.e. retrieve a list of users.

However when we try using the Mobile App with the same Endpoint it will not connect to the Web Service.

They are using a VPN to connect to their Local Network so should have permission but we think the Firewall is blocking the VPN traffic.

We have been asked if there is a port no that is used by the mobile phone. We have asked for 80, 443 to be added but still no luck.

The Mobile Phone can open up a browser and navigate to the Endpoint but just doesn't work via the Mobile APP.

Comment: what does it do?  Does it timeout?  Does it throw an exception?  Does it get any response code from the server?

Comment: We haven't got any error trapping at the moment. We will look to add this so that we have a Error Message displayed. Initial Thoughts are VPN to Server is being blocked by Firewall

Comment: if you are able to access it from the device browser then I don't see how VPN could be the issue

Comment: Yes we are able to access the Web API via the SAME Phone but using the Browser. The Web API is configured through the Application Server using IIS. Are there any Ports that need opening on the Firewall other than 80, 443 ?

Comment: @VincentLau Hi , whehther the network permission be added in Xamarin App if tested in Android device ? You can have a check with that .

Comment: @JuniorJiang-MSFT We have tested the Android Device within our Network but thats using Office WiFi. The client are using VPN to connect to their Server, which will have a firewall implemented. We think the Android Device is trying to connect to the Endpoint but it's being blocked but we cannot prove it.